# Ordering a result set on the same field in a specific query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that looks something like

```
function myFunction($team1, $team2) {
$query = "select team_name from myteam where team_id=$team1 or team_id=$team2";
}
```

the result of this always order this by the lower team_id so if it were

```
myFunction(12, 8);
```

the return would be team8 then team12. What I want to do is order the results by whichever team comes first in that query list.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myFunction($team1, $team2) {
$query = "select team_name from myteam where team_id=$team1 or team_id=$team2 ORDER BY (team_id=$team1) DESC, team_id";
}
```

Comment: +1 Surely including team_id as the second order by item is superfluous, since the query can only include a maximum of two team_id values (which have already been ordered by the conditional sort item)?

Comment: this is true. But I figured its no hair off MySQL's nuts to sort by the second element anyway, this is more extensible to other queries involving more than 2 items should he refer to this by example later. good catch :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT team_name 
  FROM myteam 
 WHERE team_id IN ($team1,$team2)
 ORDER
    BY FIELD(team_id,$team1,$team2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 function myFunction($team1, $team2) {
 $query = "select team_name from myteam where (team_id=$team1 OR team_id=$team2) ORDER BY team_id DESC";
 }
```